# Iterate over Map (Specifically TreeMap) in Java starting from a key-value pair

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap, I wanted to iterate over it and print key-value pairs. But I dont want to start from the beginning, I want to start from a particular key-value pair.

Basically I want to do this -

```
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
//Populate it here
treeMap.get("key1");
//get the iterator to the treemap starting from the key1-value1 pair and iterate
```

I know how to do this if I want to iterate from start to end, but I dont find any answers to this.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [tailMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap%28K%29) :

```
Iterator<String> iter = treeMap.tailMap("key1").keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    String value = treeMap.get(key);
    // do your stuff
}
```

or

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iter = treeMap.tailMap("key1").entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> entry = iter.next();
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: So quick, I was just waiting for eclipse to start!

Comment: yeah, better to use `Map.entrySet()` to avoid extra lookups.

Comment: @Adam Why start eclipse when you can Google the class reference? :)

Comment: @Eran Yeah I know, but I like to test my examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use `tailMap`,

```
treeMap.tailMap(fromKey)
```

You can also use it like this;

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : treeMap.tailMap("key1").entrySet()) {
   // Do something
}
```